# Why won't my 'else' statement work in python?

Tags: python, if-statement

I am just started to create a hangman game. I don't understand why my "else" statement is not working.

Here is my code:

```
while True:
    guess = input("Guess one letter in the word!: ")

    if l[0] == guess:
        print("correct")
    elif l[1] == guess:
        print("correct")
    elif l[2] == guess:
        print("correct")
    elif l[3] == guess:
        print("correct")
    elif l[4] == guess:
        print("correct")
    elif l[5] == guess:
        print("correct")
    elif l[6] == guess:
        print("correct")
    elif l[7] == guess:
        print("correct")
    elif l[8] == guess:
        print("correct")
    elif l[9] == guess:
        print("correct")
    elif l[10] == guess:
        print("correct")
    elif l[11] == guess:
        print("correct")
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
```

Comment: What is the value of `l`?

Comment: You can make it simpler by using if `string` in `word` where `word = list(word)`

Comment: What makes you think it "isn't working"?

Comment: You are confused because you don't know the values. How to know the values? Print them. `    guess = input("Guess one letter in the word!: ")
print('guess',guess,'l',l)`

Comment: `if guess in l:`...

Comment: Also, how do you know "in advance" that `l` is of length 12?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is perhaps a bit of an aside, but you could greatly simplify this by saying:

```
while True:
    guess = input("Guess one letter in the word!: ")

    if guess in l:
        print("Correct")
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
```

This would also have the side effect of allowing you to change your word to guess to one of a different length, without having to change your if/else chain.

To know why Incorrect isn't being printed, we'll need to know the value of l.

Comment: We're kind of guessing until the OP gives more details. This is a really good point though.